# Schwinger–Dyson equation represented in a different form?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, correlation-functions, 1pi-effective-action

This is a follow-up question to my earlier [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/762479/2451). The Schwinger–Dyson equation on Peskin and Schroeder reads (p.308):
$$
\left\langle\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi(x)}\int d^4x'\mathcal L\right)\phi(x_1)...\phi(x_n)\right\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \left\langle\phi(x_1)...(i\delta(x-x_i))...\phi(x_n)\right\rangle \tag{9.88}
$$

This equation tells us that the classical Euler-Lagrange equations
of the field $\phi$ are obeyed for all Green’s functions of $\phi$, up to contact terms
arising from the nontrivial commutation relations of field operators.

I also found [this reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04908) pretty helpful to study this equation. Starting from equation (5):

$$
\frac{\delta\Gamma}{\delta\phi_i} = -J_i\tag{5}
$$

We can differentiate this equation twice to obtain a relation which connects the three-point connected Green function with three-point vertex part (eq. (7)):

[image]

Where $W[J]$  is the generator of all connected
Green’s functions. We may continue and once more differentiate to obtain the relation between four- and three- and two-point Green functions, as shown in eqn. (9) in the paper, and this is called the Schwinger-Dyson equation.

I am confused about how the Schwinger-Dyson equation is represented. Does Peskin and Schroder's form the same as the one that presented in this paper?

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): The paper calls eq. (11) a SD eq, not eq. (9).

Answer (score 1):

For example, let’s consider the following Schwinger-Dyson equation.
$$0=\int D\phi\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi_y}\Big(e^{iS(\phi)+i\int_xJ\phi}\Big)$$
Taking the derivative about $\phi$, we may obtain
\begin{align}0&=\int D\phi\Big(\frac{\delta S(\phi)}{\delta\phi_y}+\int_xJ_x\delta_{x,y} \Big) e^{iS(\phi)+i\int_xJ\phi}\\
&= \int D\phi\Big(\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi_y}\Big(\frac{\delta}{i\delta J}\Big)+\int_xJ_x\delta_{x,y} \Big) e^{iS(\phi)+i\int_xJ\phi}\\
&=\Big\{-(\Box+m^2) \frac{\delta W}{\delta J}+J\Big\}Z\\
\therefore &\ \ (\Box+m^2) \frac{\delta W}{\delta J}=J\\
\therefore &\ \ (\Box+m^2) \frac{\delta W}{\delta J_x\delta J_y}=\delta_{x,y}
\end{align}
This is the Schwinger-Dyson equation for the connected Green functions.
The Klein-Gordon operator on the left-hand side is extended to $\frac{\delta\Gamma}{\delta\phi\delta\phi}$ in quantum terms. In this sense, the relational expression between the connected Green functions and the vertex functions is sometimes called the Schwinger-Dyson equation. More general equation can be obtained by taking the derivative about J.

Answer (score 1):

1. Eqs. (5) and (7)-(9) in Ref. 1 are just consequences of the [Legendre transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) between the generating functional $W_c[J]$ of connected diagrams and the [effective/proper action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_action) $\Gamma[\phi_{\rm cl}]$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107936/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. A standard consequence of the [Schwinger-Dyson (SD) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation) is $$\left<\frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta \phi^k}\right>_{\!J}~=~-J_k.\tag{A}$$

   In contrast Ref. 1 effectively considers the following main identity$^1$
   $$\begin{align}
   \exp&\left\{\frac{i}{\hbar}W_c\left[J\!+\!\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_{\rm cl}}\right]\right\}\left.\frac{\delta S[\phi_{\rm cl}]}{\delta \phi_{\rm cl}^k} \right|_{\phi_{\rm cl}=0}\cr
   ~=~&Z\left[J\!+\!\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_{\rm cl}}\right]\left.\frac{\delta S[\phi_{\rm cl}]}{\delta \phi_{\rm cl}^k} \right|_{\phi_{\rm cl}=0}\cr
   ~=~&\int\! {\cal D}\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{\hbar}} \exp\left\{\frac{i}{\hbar}(S[\phi] +J_{\ell}\phi^{\ell})+\phi^{\ell}\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi^{\ell}_{\rm cl}}\right\}\left.\frac{\delta S[\phi_{\rm cl}]}{\delta \phi_{\rm cl}^k} \right|_{\phi_{\rm cl}=0}\cr
   ~=~&\int\! {\cal D}\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{\hbar}} \exp\left\{\frac{i}{\hbar}(S[\phi] +J_{\ell}\phi^{\ell})\right\}\frac{\delta S[\phi]}{\delta \phi^k}\cr
   ~\stackrel{(A)}{=}~&-J_kZ[J],
   \end{align}\tag{B} $$
   compare with e.g. eq. (10) for $\phi^4$ theory and eqs. (12)-(14) for QED.

References:

1. B.A. Fayzullaev & E. Qayumov, *SD type equations for some QFT models,* [arXiv:2006.04908](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04908).

--

$^1$ Eqs. (3) and (6) seem different from eq. (B) as $\phi_{\rm cl}$ is presumably not put to zero.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! Why in that reference, the Schwinger-Dyson equation is called the 'full Green function'? For example, in eqn.11 and figure 3, does the SD equation tell us all the possible connected diagrams/interactions (up to some order) for a given process?

Comment: In Ref. 1 full Green function = connected Green function.